# Issue with Currency field in Datacap

Tags: ibm-datacap

We have a computer generated form and extracting a currency filed using Datacap 9.0.1. There is a strange issue

The actual value in the document say 12.02
Datacap sometimes extracts it as 12 02 i i
We used OOTB function to remove junk characters and got the result as 12 02
But the actual problem is the decimal point is missing
Is there a better way to extract currency fields? We tried image clean up, IsFieldCurrency but no use.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is use a confidence function after the capture is done.

Set the level a bit higher in order not to miss the dot, because the resolution of the image may miss the dot sometimes.

When keeping the confidence level of that field high enough, it will at least not lead to an incorrect capture.